# CompanyName in all new Xcode files not working

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Since upgrading to Xcode 4 my company name is not appearing in any new files I create instead this appears:

> Copyright 2011 **MyCompanyName**. All
>   rights reserved.

I have gone into Terminal and run the command and restarted Xcode but nothing happens:

> defaults write com.apple.Xcode
>   PBXCustomerTemplateMacroDefinitions'{"ORGANIZATIONNAME"
>   = "MyCompany";}'
>
> defaults write com.apple.Xcode
>   PBXCustomerTemplateMacroDefinitions'{'ORGANIZATIONNAME'
>   = "MyCompany";}'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the project in the navigator and open the Utility pane. The organization name is found there.

Answer (score 3):

Set your company name in your adresbook. Restart Xcode 4.
Works for Xcode 4 Build 4A304a

Answer (score 0):

#### To update all existing files, simply:

1. Press **CMD+OPTION+SHIFT+F** to open the Find and Replace.
2. Type in your old company name and the new company name.
   [image: Xcode Find and Replace]
3. Press **Replace All**

#### To change the default value of **__MyCompanyName__** for new all new files created, you can do the following:

1. Select your project in Xcode (if the Inspector isn't visible, press *CMD+1*)
   [image: Xcode Inspector]
2. In the File Inspector along the right sidebar (if the File Inspector isn't visible, press  *CMD+OPTION+1*), edit the Organization entry under the Project Document section:
   [image: Xcode File Inspector]

All new classes that are added to the project will contain this new company name.